# How to append child div into a parent div using jquery on the click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="addMore">
      <div class="row addPlus">
          <p class="emergencyTitle">Child 1</p>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
              <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name">Student Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ch1_name">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name">Class</label><br>
                      <select name="ch1_class">
                          <option value=""> 1  </option>
                          <option value=""> 2</option>
                          <option value="">  3 </option>
                      </select>
                  </div>

              </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
              <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name">DOB</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ch1_dob" id="datepicker">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name">Section</label><br>
                      <select name="ch1_secion">
                          <option value=""> A </option>
                          <option value=""> B </option>
                          <option value=""> C </option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

On the click of a button I am doing this ..

```
$child = $('.addPlus')
$('.addMore').append($child)
```

But I cannot seem to add the addPlus div, how over `$('.addMore').append("hi")` works fine. Can anyone help me out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.addPlus` is already appended to `.addMore`, so your jQuery would  work but have no effect.

Assuming you want to copy the existing instance of `.addPlus` you should call `clone()` on it before appending it to the parent, like this:

```
var $newChild = $('.addPlus').first().clone()
$('.addMore').append($newChild)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to clone the item - you can use

```
$('.addPlus').first().clone().appendTo('.addMore')
```